# Symfony2 - Configuration - inject root node parameter to get the whole configuration

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, dependencies

I wonder why it is not possible to inject the root node configuration namespace into a service.

Example configuration:

```
my_bundle: 
   foo: bar
   foobar: 123
   bar: 1
```

This would be the service configuration in MyBundle/Resources/config/services.xml.

```
...
<service id="my_bundle.service.my" class="MyService">
   <argument>%my_bundle%</argument>
</service>
...
```

Now I would like to inject the configuration into my service class. But this is not working because symfony2 does not know anything about the configuration root node "my_bundle".

```
class MyService
{
     public function __construct($config) {}
}
```

I know that I can split the config and add as many constructor arguments as I need in the service class to make it work. But this would lead to an huge amount of arguments in the constructor.

Further I think that injection of the whole symfony2 container is bad practise.

Maybe one of you can answer me: 
1. Why this can not work? 
2. Do I understand the entire configuration system wrong?
3. I thought that all what was defined under the namespace "my_bundle" is available if I inject the root node?

Or maybe anyone of you found a solution for this and share it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you bundle extension, create a parameter:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $container->setParameter('my_bundle', $config);
}
```

Then you can inject it in your service declaration

**Explanations**

What you are creating by adding options under the `my_bundle`key is a bundle configuration, which is processed in your bundle extension.

It's not a parameter defined under the `parameter` keyword, but in your bundle extension, you have access to the container, so in that place you can add this bundle configuration as a parameter (once processed, checked etc), and then inject it in your service arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me. I do not know why I did not thought about that :)